# Can you force a Binding specified in XAML to pass itself (i.e. the Binding object) and not what it evaluates to?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

We're trying to create a property that when set in XAML can either take a direct value or a `Binding` object. Note, we want to store the `Binding` ***object***, not what it evaluates to.

For the latter case, this works if the property is of type `Binding` but not if it's of type `object`, which is needed for the former case of taking a direct value.

I'm wondering if there's any way to decorate the property to say 'If someone sets a binding on you via XAML, store the `Binding` object itself, not what it evaluates to!' in essence doing the same thing as if it were of type `Binding` but still allowing it to receive other values.

Here's a walk-through to clarify what we're trying to do.  As you know, you can have this...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object Content{ get; set; }
}
```

Then using XAML you can create an instance of it and set its MyValue property like this...

```
<local:MyClass Content="Hello World" />
```

That works fine and stores the string in the property, but if you try this...

```
<local:MyClass Content="{Binding SomePath}" />
```

...it fails because MyClass is not a DependencyObject so it can't set the binding, which isn't what we want anyway.  However, if you change the property definition to this...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Binding Content{ get; set; }
}
```

It now works! Instead of attempting to evaluate the binding, it passes the `Binding` ***object*** itself to the property setter.  In other words, you aren't attaching a binding, you're storing a `Binding` object.

Since we now have the `Binding` object, we can later use it when building up the actual UI by attaching it at that time.  This is what we want.

The issue with just changing the type to `Binding` is now the original XAML where you set the property to 'Hello World' fails because it can't create a binding from that string!

That leaves us with the wonky solution of using two properties... one for non-bindings, and one for bindings...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object Content{ get; set; }
    public Binding ContentBinding{ get; set; }
}
```

...which works, but now there are two properties where we really just want one. After all, when binding to the Text property of a `TextBox`, you don't set 'TextBinding'! You just set `Text`!  That's the model we're trying to match.

The issue is it looks like the XAML parser inspects the type of the property that's being set on, and if it's anything but `Binding` (even if its `object`), it attempts to evaluate it right then.  However, if the type is `Binding`, it simply passes it along.

In short, we *always* want it passed along as a Binding object.  We *never* want it evaluated.

Is there some markup we can apply to our property to say 'Never evaluate' or is there something else we can do?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can without changing the XAML because I think a `Binding` is a markup extension. You might be able to write your own custom markup expression that returns the binding instead of the value, but that would still require a change in your XAML, so it would look something like `{local:MyBinding Text}` instead of `{Binding Text}`

Comment: THat's what one would think at first, but as illustrated above, that isn't the case when the type you're setting is of `Binding` itself.  It doesn't evaluate then.  It simply returns itself.  Perhaps the internals of the GetValue look at the return type.  Not sure.  Guess I'll dig into Reflector to see what it's doing in there.